# How to i write this problem in mathematical notation?

Tags: functions, notation

What is the notation to describe the following problem:

Using only the numbers 3,4,7 at the same time, with no repetition, write all the possible numbers.
Like,
$$374,473,437,473...$$

I tried to make 
$$
A = \{3,4,7\}  
f: x,y,z \rightarrow A, (x,y,z) \rightarrow 100x+10y+z  
$$
But what i did is possibly wrong and incomplete.

may i please u give other ideas.

thanks folks

Comment: It's unclear what you mean. Do you mean $347, 374, 437$, etc., or something like $3+4-7=0$? What work have you done yourself?

Comment: Must each number be used?  E.g., does $3$ count? Does $37$ count?

Comment: "*write all possible numbers*"... with or without operations?  What operations are allowed?  Only composition (*giving numbers like $347, 437, 374,\dots$*)?  Only addition (*giving numbers like $3+7, 4+7, 3+4+7,\dots$*)?  Literally anything is allowed, including the successor function $S(x)=x+1$ in which case you could write literally any number $n\geq 3$ as $\underbrace{S(S(\dots S}_{n-4~\text{copies}}(3)\dots)$?  If literally no operations are allowed., the list of possible numbers is simply $3,4,7$... without more detail there could be 3 possible or infinitely many or somewhere inbetween

Comment: Only composition, giving numbers like $$347,437,374$$

Comment: Now, amWhy's question should be answered.  Are numbers formed by composition which don't use all of the numbers, e.g. $3,34,4,43,\dots$, intended to be included in your list?

Comment: All the three numbers together... Ex: $$374,734$$

Comment: The answer to the question then, I should hope you can see, is simply $347,374,437,473,734,743$ and there are $3!$ such numbers.  As for how to write the question itself... I see nothing wrong with how it is written in english once you include the missing details which we asked you about, but otherwise you could rephrase the question to ask about the permutations of the set $\{3,4,7\}$ asking instead to write all possible permutations in the one-line format.

Comment: it is for didatics purposes of mathematics notation learning.

Comment: The best you've got to go with is that you are looking for all "permutations of three letters" (officially), the cardinality of which is $6$, and the elements of which are listed in JMoravitz's comment above.

Answer (score 1):

> "Find all permutations of the (multi)set $M$."

A permutation of a set is an ordered arrangement of its elements. For example, the permutations of $\{1,2,3\}$ are: $123,132,213,231,312,321$

A set cannot include repeated elements, so a multiset is needed if you want to find all numbers that can be formed by a list that includes repeats, e.g., $3,3,4,$ and $5$.

This is actually an extremely common problem in combinatorics, although it's more commonly looked at in terms of letters than numbers. This site has many examples of such problems being asked (usually asking for the number of total permutations rather than a list of them).

In terms of group,s this can be expressed as $S_{|M|}$ for the case of there being no repeats. When there are repeats, it would be $S_{|M|}/Sym_{M}$. Here $M$ is the (multi)set you are interested in the permutations of (in the example, $M=\{3,4,7\}$), $S_k$ is the [symmetric group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group) on $k$ elements, and $Sym(M)$ is the set of symmetries of $M$, i.e. the set that tells us how many of the permutations yield the same result. This is only relevent if there is repeats in the string of symbols, such as $M=\{3,3,4,7\}$. In that case our expression gives $S_4/S_2\simeq A_4$. $A_4$ (the alternating group on four elements) is the name of a particular permutation group that is the answer to the problem for the case of $M=\{3,3,47\}$

Comment: The OP is apparently looking for the notation with which to describe this problem.

Comment: if we're generalizing, difficulties occur if we are truly working with composition and some of the numbers available are two-digit or larger.  For example $\{1,2,12\}$ might treat $1~2~12$ the same as $12~1~2$.  Of course, that is a fault of the wording of the original question if that is what the OP intends

Comment: Perhaps, though that's hard to talk about without direct input from @Guilherme

Comment: thanks +Stella Biderman, i appreciate your help, but is what +amWhy said, i am looking for the notation that describe the problem, but i am glad for u help

Comment: @GuilhermeAlex Can you explain what you mean by "notation"? This is a description of the problem.

Comment: +Stella Biderman , This is a list of symbols found within all branches of mathematics to express a formula or to represent a constant. From wikipedia.

Comment: Well, Stella, you seemed to criticize my post as failing to name the problem, so I'm surprised only now you allow that your failure is do to the asker's confusion. You seem to have failed describing the problem adequately.  Of course you've made multiple edits, as you learn more and more from the OP, but the point is, so it's sort of a work in progress?

Comment: @GuilhermeAlex The appropriate way to specify this problem is to ask for the permutations of the set $\{3,4,7\}$. Read my last paragraph about the concept of notation. If you mean how to express the *answer* then amWhy's answer of $3!$ is appropriate and commonly used, as is $_3P_3$ or $P(3,3)$

Comment: well Stella, i read. But in this case, i need the notation of that problem.

Comment: @GuilhermeAlex Does my new last line address what you're looking for?

Comment: Stella Could you define $S_{|M|}$?  Are you trying to invoke the symmetric group on three elements, e.g., $M = \{3, 4, 7\}$?  You're off the mark.

Comment: Stella it confused me a little bit ... I think it can be done using symmetric groups like you described. I need to research.

Comment: @GuilhermeAlex  The symmetric group on $\{3, 4, 7\}$ is given by $\{id, (34), (37), (47), (347), (374)\}$.  It does not include $(473)$ nor $(437)$, nor (734) nor (7430) because as permutations, they are equivalent to a permutation in the symmetric group. $473= 347 = 734$, and $(437) = (374) = (743).$

Comment: I got it ... i am glad for your explanation +amWhy ... then, the symmectric group is not the answer.